# Is it okay to use high dimensional data for QQ plots comparison?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I had a question regarding using high-dimensional data for a QQ plot. I have some audio signal data with dimensions:
`data.shape = (3035, 180)`

I first used this code:

`scipy.stats.probplot(data, dist="norm", plot=plt);`

Which threw this error:

`ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 3035 and the array at index 1 has size 180`

So I reshaped the data to fix the error:

`new_size = 3035 * 180`

`measurements = np.array(data).reshape(new_size)`

This flattened my data into a 1-dimensional array, which now I was able to plot the QQ plot:
[image]

My questions are this:

1. is it valid to reshape higher dimensional data in order to check if the data is normally distributed using a QQ plot?
2. If 1 is valid then how can I interpret this plot? it looks like it matches the regression line really well in the middle, but then gets worse on the tail ends?

Comment: I suspect you have 3035 columns (variables) and 180 rows (observations)? Flattening means to put all the columns in one column. Question is: why should this follow a normal distribution - what is the data generating process, what is your aim? As you correctly say, the falttened data do approximate a normal distribution in "the middle", but towards the 90-95 percentile of the distribution, there are extreme "outliers".